# java.sql.SQLException: HikariDataSource HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1) has been closed

Tags: java, spring

> Exception in thread "task-2" org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.UncategorizedScriptException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: HikariDataSource HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1) has been closed.

I have an SQL script that just inserts some records on app start

`spring.datasource.data=classpath:kana.sql`

It seems to run through about 10-20 just fine and then suddenly it quits

My `application.properties`:

```
## default connection pool
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=20000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=5

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

## PostgreSQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://10.0.0.100:5432/langsite
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.data=classpath:kana.sql

server.port=4000

#drop n create table again, good for testing, comment this in production
# javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=create
# javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source=metadata
# javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source=metadata
```

It seems to connect successfully initially, because it can create the tables, insert a few records, but then part-way through the insertions it just craps out.

Comment: Daniil Bratin is right about the conflict. As stated [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M7/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html):
`In a JPA-based app, you can choose to let Hibernate create the schema or use schema.sql, but you cannot do both. Make sure to disable spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto if you use schema.sql.` For the error, try to increase the maximumPoolSize. This [article](https://medium.com/@rajchandak1993/understanding-hikaricps-connection-pooling-behaviour-467c5a1a1506) explains how Hikari connection pool works under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your app runs out of available connections in the pool.
I guess these two things conflicting:

this

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

and this

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.data=classpath:kana.sql
```

If you want to create schema by Hibernate try this option to load initial data

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files=classpath:kana.sql
```

Anyway refer this article. It should help
https://dimitr.im/loading-initial-data-with-spring